# Unable to include C++ header file while compiling

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 2 files in my package

1. A c++ class file (example_ros_class.cpp)
2. roscpp file that uses the header of the first file (implementation.cpp)

using catkin_make, i receive this error code

Here's the error code

```
fatal error: example_ros_class.h: No such file or directory
 #include "example_ros_class.h"
```

I have tried to follow this documentation

- https://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_libraries.html
- http://answers.ros.org/question/65716/which-is-the-correct-way-to-install-header-files-in-catkin-packages/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/45422/ros-c-custom-header-not-found/

and so fort

Here's my CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(eg_ros_class)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES eg_ros_class
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)

##BUILD##
include_directories(
  include
  src/eg_ros_class
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(eg_ros_class src/example_ros_class.cpp)

add_executable(eg_ros_class_exe src/example_ros_class.cpp)
target_link_libraries(eg_ros_class ${catkin_LIBRARIES}, )

add_executable(implementation_exe src/implementation.cpp)
target_link_libraries(implementation_exe ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(implementation_exe eg_ros_class_generate_messages_cpp)

##Install##
catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include
               LIBRARIES eg_ros_class)
 install(TARGETS eg_ros_class
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )

 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326427/unable-to-include-c++-header-file-while-compiling/) by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My answer is just guessing, so i point out certain potential concerns related to your implementation, in numbered points.

1. You should paste a bigger piece of error message.

If you have only two files in your package, most likely you have `#include "example_ros_class.h"` in the **example_ros_class.cpp** resulting in `fatal error: example_ros_class.h: No such file or directory`

2. Your **CMakeLists.txt** contains a lot of mistakes

A fixed file would look like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(eg_ros_class)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  # (A) INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES eg_ros_class
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
  # (B) DEPENDS system_lib
)

##BUILD##
include_directories(
  include
  # (C) src/eg_ros_class
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  # (D) ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  # (E) ${GSTREAMER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(eg_ros_class src/example_ros_class.cpp)

add_executable(eg_ros_class_exe src/example_ros_class.cpp)
# (F) target_link_libraries(eg_ros_class ${catkin_LIBRARIES}, )
target_link_libraries(eg_ros_class ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(implementation_exe src/implementation.cpp)
target_link_libraries(implementation_exe ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(implementation_exe eg_ros_class_generate_messages_cpp)

##Install##
# (G)
#catkin_package(INCLUDE_DIRS include
#               LIBRARIES eg_ros_class)
# install(TARGETS eg_ros_class
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )E_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )
```

2 A. You wrote that your project contains only two files, so include directory is empty. In this case this line is not needed.

2 B. What is a **system_lib**? It's probably the name used as an example in the template **CMakeLists.txt**.

2 C. In this line you should include only headers

2 D and 2E. It depends on if you using Boost or GStreamer library. Are you using?

2 F. Freaky comma before parenthesis. Fixed in the next line: `target_link_libraries(eg_ros_class ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

2 G. You don't need use **catkin_package** again

---

Originally posted by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) with karma: 290 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dickson](https://answers.ros.org/users/43223/dickson/) on 2019-06-23**:
Hello! Thank you for your guidance

I manage to get it working now.
Just using

include_directories(
include
${eg_ros_class} #package_name
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)